# AspNetCoreModule - what is minimum IIS server version?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I can't find an information what is the minimum IIS version required to install AspNetCoreModule in order to host asp.net core application on IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module) says about OS - Windows 7 is needed at least to install ASP.NET Core Module:

> Supported Windows versions:
>
> Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 and later

And Windows 7 and Server 2008 comes with IIS 7.5.

Comment: oh, i completely forgot about IIS version being strictly bound to OS version. You are completely right. Thanks!